# Filter Mysql Query after it has been stored in php variable

Tags: php, mysql

So i am coding this program which is essentially a back-end system to asterisk, that displays all calls, call time, call dates, usernames etc to management. The way it was before was that you had a for loop looping over all users in the database. Inside that was a number of functions, and each function always used to call this statement:

```
 $stmt="select callcharge,billsec,src,dst,calldate from cdr where (src='$ext[$x]' or src='238800$ext[$x]') and calldate>='$startdate' and calldate<='$stopdate' and length(dst)>3 and (dst like '7%' or dst like '9%') and billsec>5";
    $result=mysql_query ($stmt);
```

and it would do this for all the users(each with their own unique extension) {VERY VERY SLOWW!}

Now i am trying to reduce load time, by instead, calling this statement once outside of the for loop:

```
$stmtf="select callcharge,billsec,src,dst,calldate from cdr where calldate>='$startdate' and calldate<='$stopdate' and length(dst)>3 and dst like '2%' and billsec>5";
```

$results=mysql_query ($stmtf);

notice that it is not filtering by extension number anymore (it calls all the info for every extension number)

now what i want to do is this: after calling this mysql query just once and now all data is stored in the variable $stmtf, i want to be able to go into the for loop and somehow filter that $stmtf variable with this query `(src='$ext[$x]' or src='238800$ext[$x]')`

My goal here, is to make a request to the database once instead of making a ton of requests to the database from the for loop, since the data i need is the same, just for a different extension number.

Comment: Provide a print_r() of your array structure.

Comment: print_r() of $results returned: 'Resource id #10'

Comment: Well, there's your first issue. You'll need to loop through your result and add each row to an array. That will essentially give you an array that is made up of arrays.

Comment: You can just process all results from your new query and sort them by `src` by storing them in an intermediate multidimensional array, where the first key would be the `src`.

Comment: @RemcoOverdijk , once i do so, how will i be able to call a row for a particular extension number? say i want to use the rows for extension number '98' ? thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code to illustrate my comment:

```
<?php
/**
 * STORING THE RECORDS SORTED BY EXTENSION
 */
$stmtf="select callcharge,billsec,src,dst,calldate from cdr where calldate>='{$startdate}' and calldate<='{$stopdate}' and length(dst)>3 and dst like '2%' and billsec>5";
$results=mysql_query ($stmtf);
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) { // cycle each result returned by the query.
    $row['src'] = substr_replace("238800","",$row['src']); //normalize the 'src' to one format.
    $data[$row['src']][] = $row; //store the record in a sub-array, sorted by 'src' as the first key.
}
print_r($data); //echo the sorted results for debugging.

/**
 * CALLING THE ROWS FOR EXTENSION '98'
 */

foreach($data['98'] as $record) { //if all extensions are numeric, $data[98] will also work.
    print_r($record); //each record contained in the sub-array for '98' is printed individually.
}
?>
```

Comment: Oh That makes perfect sense! i just tryed it and it worked like a charm! also, loading time is MUCH MUCH FASTER! thanks @Remco Overdijk !

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the query results, something like:

```
$stmtf="select callcharge,billsec,src,dst,calldate from cdr where calldate>='$startdate' and calldate<='$stopdate' and length(dst)>3 and dst like '2%' and billsec>5";

$results=mysql_query ($stmtf);

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
//access vars like this - $row['callcharge']
}
```

https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc

Oh and you might want to think about curbing the use of the mysql library, it is being phased out.

Comment: Brilliant! so once i do that, i can pull rows with a specific extension number right?

Comment: You can only put checks in that only perform actions on certain rows, for example if($row['whatever']=='xyz'){//do something}